# Expand maximum multiplayer limit

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friends and I play Minecraft Bedrock Edition together. However, when there are more than 5 people I can't get the others to join.

I have access to a separate PC if that helps. If not, does anyone know of a way to bypass the default player limit on iOS/Android devices?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but 1.1.0 adds the `/setmaxplayers` command, which can be set to a number higher than 5. Not sure if it actually changes it.

Comment: Quick note to the people reviewing my edit, the people reading this, and the poster: They want to get past the limit on **Xbox live or LAN, not a dedicated or rented server.** I can say this with 100% confidence as dedicated servers only exist on Windows 10 and Ubuntu, and he clearly isn't renting a server because he is asking for iOS and Android in specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you started a server the default player limit is 20 players.  You can change this, but if you are only playing with a group of friends, 20 should be plenty.

This site explains how to download a server:
http://www.howtogeek.com/202961/how-to-run-a-local-minecraft-pe-server-for-fun-and-persistent-world-building/

This site holds the download:
http://www.pocketmine.net/

LAN does have its limitations and going around them is easiest.

Comment: I have heard of pocket mine before, and I tried your suggestion but I can't figure out how to use my already existing MCPE world on it. Do you know of any guides that can help? Also, thanks for your response!

Comment: I only know of a way to do it on a PC.  As for device with PE I don't think you can.  I know you can connect PE with a windows 10 computer so if you look into that you may be able to have more players.  Like I said, PE does have its limitations, but maybe in  the future there will be an easy way.

Comment: No problem.  I'll post if i find anything new.

Answer (score 0):

Activate cheat on your server and then insert the command:

`/setmaxplayers n`

The n stands for the number of players you want on your server.

Answer (score -2):

I'm adding to the above answer, not enough rep. I'm pretty sure if you're on android or Win 10 edition you can nav to directory,

(Android = `sdcard/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds` or something similar

win 10 = `C:\Users\somethingsomething\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang`

Never used IOS so i don't know about that.

Comment: I think the programs may need special apps to open them so that mobile devices can't read them, and even if you manage, the programs might be too long and confusing *only* to change the player limit. I think that such a piece of code is stored in the online database of Minecraft servers, because if it was stored in a player's client and a fool changed it, some client-sided errors related to multiplayer connections may occur. I also heard that the error "This server responded with an invalid server key" appears when the game detects inappropriate server configurations. So this is a bad idea.