# How to change max players without enabling cheats

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Per the title, I wish to know how I can change the max number of players allowed on my MinecraftPE world/server without losing any achievements (Or the ability to earn them).

I am using iPadOS, but could also use iOS to make the changes. The world is saved locally.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand maximum multiplayer limit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/256271/expand-maximum-multiplayer-limit) (per answer)

Answer (score -1):

An answer in the related thread [Expand maximum multiplayer limit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/256271/expand-maximum-multiplayer-limit):

> If you started a server the default player limit is 20 players. You can change this, but if you are only playing with a group of friends, 20 should be plenty.
> This site explains how to download a server: http://www.howtogeek.com/202961/how-to-run-a-local-minecraft-pe-server-for-fun-and-persistent-world-building/
> This site holds the download: http://www.pocketmine.net/
> LAN does have its limitations and going around them is easiest.
> If you started a server the default player limit is 20 players. You can change this,

Credit goes to [@Jason_](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/138887/jason) for answer.

Comment: I want to know how to change the limit on an existing (MCPE) world, I do not want to create a new server.